# logout commandLink logs the user out, but doesn't update the page

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jboss6.x

I have a logout link in my JSF app that invalidates the session to log the user out.  It works but it doesn't redirect the user to the logon page.  It stays on the same page.  If I try to access the same page again it does direct back to the logon.  I want this to happen immediately.

logout link:

```
<h:form>
    <h:panelGroup id="loginout">
        <h:outputText value="#{todoController.loggedInUser}" />
        <h:commandLink value="logout" action="#{todoController.logout}" />
    </h:panelGroup>         
</h:form>
```

logout code:

```
public String logout()
{
    System.out.println("testing logout");
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();

    final HttpServletRequest r = (HttpServletRequest)ec.getRequest();
    r.getSession( false ).invalidate();

    return "../login.html?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can happen if the outcome is invalid. `login.html` doesn't seem to be a JSF page, so JSF navigation will simply fail.

You want to use [`ExternalContext#redirect()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect%28java.lang.String%29) instead.

```
public void logout() throws IOException {
    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    ec.invalidateSession();
    ec.redirect("../login.html");
}
```

*Note that the above also demonstrates a more JSF-ish way to invalidate the session. Whenever you need to haul the raw `javax.servlet.*` API from under the JSF hoods, you should always ask yourself twice: "Is there **really** not a JSF-provided API for this?"*

Comment: Thanks.  This worked.  However when trying to login after the redirection I get a "HTTP Status 408 error - The time allowed for the login process has been exceeded".  I've redirected instead to the original page which then jumps to the login page since you aren't logged in anymore. :-)